# Escreva um programa em python que leia um número inteiro com 8 algarismos

Tags: python

Escreva um programa que leia um número inteiro com 8 algarismos. A saída do seu programa deverá ser o resultado da soma de todos os algarismos do número inteiro informado. Caso o número digitado não tenha 8 algarismos, o programa deve escrever 'NAO SEI' (sem acentos e aspas).

IMPORTANTE: Você deverá resolver este problema usando estrutura de repetição. Do contrário, a nota será zero.

```
Exemplo 1:

Entrada:

123

Saída:

NAO SEI



Exemplo 2:

Entrada:

34576890

Saída:

42
```

Pessoal eu fiz o seguinte código porem minha nota continua 5 de 10 e acho que o problema é nessa parte do:

```
 if n<=1:
    print("NAO SEI")
```

pois o programa quer que caso o número digitado não tenha 8 algarismos, o programa deve escrever 'NAO SEI'

```
n=int(input("valor de n:"))

soma=0

while n>0:

resto=n%10

n=(n-resto)//10

soma=soma+resto

print(soma)

if n<=1:

print("NAO SEI")
```

Answer (score 4):

A melhor forma de se resolver é:

```
numero = input('Número: ')

if len(numero) == 8:
    print(sum(map(int, numero)))
else:
    print('NAO SEI')
```

Que poderia, inclusive, ser reduzido para:

```
numero = input('Número: ')

print(sum(map(int, numero)) if len(numero) == 8 else 'NAO SEI')
```

Sem prejudicar a legibilidade e semântica do código. Mas, como pede explicitamente para utilizar laços de repetição, que, provavelmente seja para treinar tal estrutura, você pode resolver da seguinte forma:

```
algarismos = input('Número: ')

if len(algarismos) == 8:
    numero = int(algarismos)
    soma = 0
    while numero > 0:
        soma += numero % 10
        numero = numero//10
    print(soma)
else:
    print('NAO SEI')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/AgedGrotesqueAudit)</sup>

Basicamente a única diferença para o seu código, desconsiderando os erros de indentação na pergunta, é que verifiquei o número de algarismos do número enquanto ele ainda era uma *string*, no retorno de `input`.

A questão a levantar é: o número `"01234567"` deve ser considerado como 8 algarismos ou 7? Se for 8, o tratamento com *string* é o mais simples, mas, se for 7, o número deverá ser um tipo numérico mesmo, então o ideal seria verificar se o mesmo está dentro do intervalo `[100000000, 99999999]`:

```
numero = int(input('Número: '))

if 10000000 <= numero <= 99999999:
    soma = 0
    while numero > 0:
        soma += numero % 10
        numero = numero//10
    print(soma)
else:
    print('NAO SEI')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/BigheartedWavySpof)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma de resolver esta questão é utilizando os conceitos de função juntamente com o laço de repetição for.

Uma das formas que podemos implementar o código é:

```
def soma_digitos(n):
    if len(n) == 8:
        return sum([int(i) for i in n])
    return 'NAO SEI'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    numero = input('Digite um número: ')
    resultado = soma_digitos(numero)

    print(f'{resultado}')
```

Observe que este código captura o valor digitado na forma de `string`, repassa este valor, como parâmetro, para a função `soma_digitos()`. Chegando lá, é verificado o tamanho da string. Se este tamanho for **igual** a **8**, será montada outra lista, na qual cada um de seus elementos é um inteiro e, em seguida, com ajuda da função `sum`, será calculada a soma de seus valores, sendo posteriormente exibido o retorno.

Agora, caso o tamanho da lista seja **diferente** de **8** o retorno exibido será a mensagem **NAO SEI**.